# JAVAFX custom icons on dialogs not working

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

All,
I have inherited some code that I am just cleaning up and doing some tweaks to. The 1st thing I want to do is add the custom icon to all the popups in the application. However, I am running into some roadblocks.
Here is the current piece of code I am working with:

```
    onDeleteClick(ActionEvent event) {
    // delete 
    System.out.println("Deleting");

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "do you want to delete?", ButtonType.YES,
            ButtonType.NO);
    alert.setTitle("Delete ");
    alert.setHeaderText("You are about to delete " + code.getText());
    alert.initOwner(((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()); //recently added displays correct icon
    alert.showAndWait();

    if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {
    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(); //progress indicator does not display correctly
    VBox box = new VBox(pi);
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    final Stage Dialog = new Stage();
    Dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Dialog.setTitle("Deleting, Please Wait!");
            
    // Get the Stage.  I found this code but it does not display the custom icon.
    //Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    // Add a custom icon.
    //Dialog.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("my.ico").toString()));
    
    Dialog.centerOnScreen();
    Dialog.setHeight(200);
    Dialog.setWidth(300);
    Dialog.setResizable(false);
        
    TilePane tp = new TilePane();
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Please wait for deletion to complete."); // added due to progress indicator failure

    tp.getChildren().add(label);
    tp.getChildren().add(pi);
    Scene 1Scene = new Scene(tp);
            
    Dialog.setScene(1Scene);
    Dialog.show();
```

Thanks for any help/direction with displaying the custom icon in the dialog.

Comment: Does JavaFX [support](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) `*.ico` images?

Comment: I'm specifically referring to the icon in the upper left had corner of the dialog.  Currently the *.ico file displays on Alerts and the main scene/page of the application. Thanks.

Comment: I know which icon you're talking about, but it still uses `javafx.scene.image.Image`, which doesn't seem to explicitly mention supporting `*.ico` format. But if you can display the image otherwise, then I guess it is supported.

Comment: Provide the source icon image.

Comment: Follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), so it is easier to read.  (Don't put numbers at the start of variable names, don't capitalize variables).  Indent code (use the code formatting capabilities of your IDE).  Try to provide just a small Application class that can be copy and pasted without change or addition to replicate the issue and nothing else.

Comment: Even if `.ico` worked for you, it [doesn't seem to be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474791/javafx-2-2-image-support-for-ico) and a [change request to add support](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092240) is open and not closed.  So I would advise using a more common format as recommended in the linked answer.

Comment: JavaFX 8 is obsolete, I recommend using a modern version, e.g. 18+.